# How do you submit a form with javascript with a <input type="button">

Tags: javascript, html

How would you use a div to submit a form, for example? Javascript please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById("ID of form element").submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an onchange event attached to a dropdown that does:

```
this.form.submit();
```

It's used on an internal utility, so I'm not sure if there is a cross-browser issue, but it's great on IE 7, firefox 3.x, and safari.