# When Web Browsing from code, how do you send information to an <input .* type="Submit"> and retrieve the resulting link?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, f#, browser

Similar threads may be:

[How do I programmatically send information to a web service in C# with .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564352/how-do-i-programmatically-send-information-to-a-web-service-in-c-sharp-with-net)
[Maintain button submit value when using link to submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058326/maintain-button-submit-value-when-using-link-to-submit-a-form)
[Looking how to send multiple values with an input type=submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423087/looking-how-to-send-multiple-values-with-an-input-type-submit-form)
[How send a form with Javascript when input name is "submit"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729319/how-send-a-form-with-javascript-when-input-name-is-submit)
[How do you submit a form with javascript with an < input type="button">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785357/how-do-you-submit-a-form-with-javascript-with-a-input-type-button)

...All of the above seem to almost answer the question...but I'm totally mystified. I think something along the lines of "Net.Post(something)" is how it is done...but I am not sure.

I am currently using F#, and I have figured out how to parse links.  I also figured out how to catch the various search bars and submission buttons with regexes.
I would like to use my code to search for something on a search engine by specifically:

**First**, obtaining the HTML

**Second**, Scraping the HTML for the various buttons, text bars, and links

**Third**, use some unknown method/device/tool/function to send a search thread to a text box...

**Fourth**, Simulate an actual mouse click on the submit "button" that appears on the website...

...

Then, upon reciept of the server's response, pull the HTML from the next site.
Here is my link code as it stands:

```
    type Url(x:string)=  
     member this.Tostring  = sprintf "%A" x
     member this.Request   = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(x)
     member this.Response  = this.Request.GetResponse()
     member this.Stream    = this.Response.GetResponseStream()
     member this.Reader    = new System.IO.StreamReader(this.Stream)
     member this.Html      = this.Reader.ReadToEnd()   
    let linkex                = "href=\s*\"[^\"h]*(http://[^&\"]*)\"" 

    let getLinks (txt:string) = [for m in Regex.Matches(txt,linkex)  
                                  -> m.Groups.Item(1).Value        ] 

    let collectLinks (url:Url) =   url.html 
                                |> getLinks
```

... I know how to grab the search box strings and whatnot...the question is, when I go to, say, google.com and grab the search bar the same way I grab the links, update the value field with my search string, how do I then submit the updated search bar to google's server?

Secondly, how do I do it if I want to update it and then simulate a mouse click?

In other words, I want to interact with websites the way the user interacts with websites.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two options - some web pages accept data using HTTP GET (which means that the data is sent as part of the URL) and other use HTTP POST (which means that the data is sent as the body of the request).

If you're using i.e. Google, then you can use **HTTP GET** and put the query string in the URL. For example, you can just download a web page with the following URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=hello. So, all you need to do is to generate the URL as follows:

```ml
let search = sprintf "http://www.google.com/search?q=%s"
```

If you want to send **HTTP POST** request from F#, then you need to create a request with body that contains the form values in an encoded form. This can be written as follows:

```ml
open System.Text
open System.IO
open System.Net

// URL of a simple page that takes two HTTP POST parameters. See the
// form that submits there: http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.html
let url = "http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.cgi"

// Create & configure HTTP web request
let req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest 
req.ProtocolVersion <- HttpVersion.Version10
req.Method <- "POST"

// Encode body with POST data as array of bytes
let postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fname=Tomas&lname=Petricek")
req.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength <- int64 postBytes.Length
// Write data to the request
let reqStream = req.GetRequestStream() 
reqStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
reqStream.Close()

// Obtain response and download the resulting page 
// (The sample contains the first & last name from POST data)
let resp = req.GetResponse() 
let stream = resp.GetResponseStream() 
let reader = new StreamReader(stream) 
let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Aside, your use of `type` with `member` for every step is a bit weird. Members are re-executed each time you access them, so the code you wrote is pretty non-deterministic. You should use `let` binding instead.

Comment: Well, using members is also problematic because you do not properly close the request and other objects that implement `IDisposable`. To keep things simple, I also didn't do that in my snippet, but it actually should be done. In normal code, this is quite easy - just use `use` instead of `let`, but doing that with members is going to be really difficult. I don't understand why you choose to use `type` for this. Maybe there is a way to solve the problem you were trying to solve, more elegantly?

Comment: @ChristopherDonlan profile != always correct :-). You're right that non-deterministic isn't correct word. What I mean is that property evaluates when it is accessed (and each time it is accessed), not in the order in which they are defined. This means that, for example accessing `Response` multiple times will send requests repeatedly and it is generally hard to tell when what part of the code runs (this is why doing I/O is difficult in lazy languages...)